# What is a dependent class?

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to understand loose coupling vs tight coupling, and I've hit a wall regarding the word dependent class. Can someone please tell me/or provide an example of what is a dependent class?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide an example ? Given your question, I would **guess** that a "dependant" class would need the header of the class on which it depends (so tight coupling), whereas loose coupling means a forward-declaration is enough.

Comment: Nevertheless "dependency" is often used as a generic term for "using/knowing" objects of other classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly related to C++ and is not a direct C++ programming problem. But in your context the word dependence refers to the `UML`.

`UML` or the  Unified Modeling Language is a design language that uses diagrams to illustrate the architecture and interaction of code, and is a handy tool to visualize object oriented systems.

When 1 class has a dependence on another it indicates that there is an arrow originating on the dependent class and terminating on the depended-on class.

Dependence can be loosely defined as there exist calls to the methods of 1 class in another or there exist initializations of objects of 1 class in another. Implying that the latter depends on the former

like this

[image]

Read more here: https://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language

Comment: Also I have this statement: "Mediator promotes loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction independently." "Referring to each other" means using a pointer or a reference to access an object?

Comment: That refers to the [Mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) pattern. It's one from among a technique of object oriented programming paradigms called "Design Patterns". Deisgn patterns are often modelled using UML. Yes in this context `class a` and `class c` would use a mediator `class b` to use each other's functionality. To answer your question, yes. Referring to each other through an explicit object, a pointer or another means of accessing directly.